# deleting data from database, "The GET method is not supported"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2

Trying to delete data from database and this is how I am using controller and route for this:

**controller**

```
public function articleDelete($id)
{

    return $article = Article::destroy($id);

    // return response()->json([
    //     "article" => $article,
    //     "message" => "Deleted Successfully"
    // ]);

}
```

**api**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function(){
    /* fetch */
    Route::get("/articles", "Api\ArticlesController@allArticles");
    Route::get("/articles/{id}", "Api\ArticlesController@singleArticle");

    /* add new & delete */
    Route::post("articles/add", "Api\ArticlesController@newArticle");
    Route::delete("articles/delete/{id}", "Api\ArticlesController@articleDelete");
});
```

and this is my method in **vue components**:

```
methods: {
    deleteArticle(article, id){
        axios.delete("api/v1/articles/delete/" + article.id).then(response => {
            let index = this.articles.indexOf(article);
            this.articles.splice(index,1);
            console.log(response.data);
        })
    },
}
```

when I adding new article there no problem. But when I try to delete article there are errors. First in console, id is being undefined which is `.../api/v1/articles/delete/undefined`

and the this is the error.

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
>   POST.

I am already using post for the route why it s keep saying "get method is not supported." I am not using get for the route. And I cleared **route:clear** and checked, there is no problem route is on post.

What I am missing here? Thank you.

**Additionally** I am giving the key prop when I looping the datas.

```
<tr :key="item.id" v-for="(item, index) in fetchArticle">
    <td>{{item.entry}}</td>
    <td>{{item.company_name}}</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteArticle(item.id)" :id="item.id">delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

I don't understand why ID part is being undefined.

Comment: Make sure `article.id` has correct id or it's not passing undefine

Comment: One more suggestion always use `delete` method for delete data API.

Comment: oh, I updated the method as delete after that. let me update question too, but nothing is changed... And update the event button code as well, could you check it out?

Comment: Have you checked `article.id`?

Comment: Oh I solved the problem! I will post the answer now.

Comment: There is any change in message :- `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.` ? I mean POST is changed by DELETE?

Comment: I'm waiting for solution.

Comment: post it. it's a bit my mistake though... thank you for the suggestions. @SahilGupta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. it's a bit my mistake though.

I changed the route post to delete

```
Route::delete("articles/delete/{id}", "Api\ArticlesController@articleDelete");
```

And in vue component did some changes.

```
deleteArticle(id){
     axios.delete("api/v1/articles/delete/" + id).then(response => {
        let index = this.articles.indexOf(id);
        this.articles.splice(index,1);
        console.log(response.data);
     })
},
```

also the event button I changed it like below.

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteArticle(item.id)" :id="item.id">delete</button></td>
```

I hope it helps for others too...

Comment: Please consider accepting your own answer so this question is marked as solved! Glad you figured it out.

Comment: i can't accept my answer right away. need to wait 2 days... @Fjarlaegur

Comment: Ah my bad! Accept it whenever you can then.

Answer (score 1):

```
//change route code
Route::delete("articles/delete/{id}", "Api\ArticlesController@articleDelete");
//change vue code
axios.delete("api/v1/articles/delete/" + article.id).then(response => {
```

I'm a beginner, you can try my method, I hope I can help you.